# How can i add cooling fan 12v in series or parallel with a 6v led diode

Tags: led, fan

what resistor do i need for this circuit in parallel

12v dc 1000ma power supply

connected in parallel:

1) 6v 800ma LED

2) 12V 90ma fan

will i be good with a resistor of 22ohms before the 6v led?

Thankyou

Comment: Ummm.  Really?  Are you using a constant current power source?  If so, then it will be trying to push 1A through your 800mA LED - regardless of the resistor.  A constant current source would jack up the voltage to try to hold the current constant at 1A.  So, your resistor would only help if the constant current power supply had hit the top end of its voltage range before reaching 1A.  Please verify your power supply.  It seems more likely that you have a standard 12V, 1A power supply.

Comment: standard 12v plug

Comment: @aetdinger: Please use proper capitalisation an punctuation in your sentences and for engineering units - "V" for volt, "A" for amp, etc. - and for acronyms "LED", "DC", etc. It will make your posts more readable, the author seem more intelligent and it's standard English.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple.

The fan goes directly to the 12V.

The led goes to the 12V with a resistor in series.
R value = V/I = (12V - 6V)/800 mA = 7.5 ohm.
E12 range 2 resistors of 15 ohm in parallel.
A higher resistor value is possible but then you do not have 800 mA.

A little more complex but to prevent the high energie loss (heat) replacing the resistor with a little convertor 12/6 V could improve the solution.

Comment: so add 2x 15 ohms resistor in series before the led, sorry novice normally only use series parrallel is new to me

Comment: @aetdinger See reformated answer from Decapod.    @ Decapod - please excuse refprmating - seemed best way to easily answer his follow on question. ie all infor was there but as no line breaks he seemed to miss it.

Answer (score 0):

> 12 V DC 1000 mA constant current driver.

You need to be sure that the maximum voltage this power supply will output is 12 V. You can check this with a voltmeter and no load on the power supply. The caution is that you have also specified that it is a 1000 mA *constant current* PSU and that means that it will increase its output voltage as much as it can to drive 1000 mA into the load. If that maximum is 12 V then you're OK.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzYDxp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Wiring of fan and LED.*

The problem with your design is that R1 will have to dissipate as much power as the LED. \$ P = VI = 6 \times 0.8 = 4.8~W \$. This will get hot. Bear in mind that resistors' power ratings may apply when the temperature is close to 90°C. As always, read the datasheet.

Your constant current power supply is probably switched mode type and will be designed to be much more efficient than the resistor when powering the LED on its own.

Your proposed solution is not ideal but it will work.

Comment: Question has been updated.  He's not using a constant current power supply.